# Product not shown with relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this two tables:

One is Product Table :

| id | Title | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | Product 2 | 7000 |

and the other is product attribute table:

| id | product_id | attribute_id | attribute_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | Color | Red |
| 2 | 1 | 6 | Size | XL |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | Color | Green |

Product and Product attribute is related with following relation (In the product model):

```
 public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsAttribute::class, 'product_id ');
    }
```

I'm fetching data like this :

```
return Product::with('attributes')
        ->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attribute_id,$attribute_value){
            $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attribute_id);
            $query->whereIn('value', $attribute_value);
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```

Issue is if there is no attribute in the product attribute table which are related to a particular product then that product is not shown in the search, but my requirement is if related attribute is not there then also product should be shown in the result.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As a sidenote, be careful using the name `attributes`; Models already have a property `$model->attributes`, which is an array of their database columns, and naming a relationship `public function attributes()` might have unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the constraint in the `whereHas` that is why it excludes the product records from the results where the condition evaluates to false.

Try

```php
return Product::with(['attributes' => function ($query) use ($attribute_id,$attribute_value){
            $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attribute_id)
                ->whereIn('value', $attribute_value);
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```